# How to create own screen time app (Same as Apple) using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I need to create own screen time app in that I should be able to track which app is being used for how much time in mins/hours is that possible for us?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is available only for the operating system. You cannot observe the screen time of the other applications except yours for security reasons.